# How to draw U.S. state map with HI and AK, with state abbreviations centered, using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've used geom_map with map_data but that doesn't include HI and AK. I've used US census geographic boundary data of US states with geom_polygon, and state.center but they don't match up. I've read related posts on stackoverflow but those I've read don't really answer my question. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
library(choroplethr)
library(ggplot2)
library(devtools)
install_github('arilamstein/choroplethrZip@v1.3.0')
library(choroplethrZip)

data(df_zip_demographics)
df_zip_demographics$value = df_zip_demographics$percent_asian

zip_map = ZipChoropleth$new(df_zip_demographics)
zip_map$ggplot_polygon = geom_polygon(aes(fill = value),
                                      color = NA)
zip_map$set_zoom_zip(state_zoom = NULL,
                     county_zoom = NULL,
                     msa_zoom = NULL,
                     zip_zoom = NULL)
zip_map$title = "50 State Map for StackOverflow"
zip_map$legend = "Asians"
zip_map$set_num_colors(4)
choro = zip_map$render()
choro

data(df_pop_state)
outline = StateChoropleth$new(df_pop_state)
outline = outline$render_state_outline(tolower(state.name))

choro_with_outline = choro + outline
choro_with_outline
```

Also, here is the code that adds state labels: https://github.com/arilamstein/choroplethr/blob/master/R/state.R#L33

[image: 50 states]

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to re-think your strategy a bit since you'll need to move some of the state labels for readability. Prbly shld draw a line from the state to the label for the ones you move, too.

```
library(ggplot2)   
library(ggalt)     # coord_proj
library(albersusa) # devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/albersusa")
library(ggthemes)  # theme_map
library(rgeos)     # centroids
library(dplyr)

# composite map with AK & HI
usa_map <- usa_composite()

# calculate the centroids for each state
gCentroid(usa_map, byid=TRUE) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(state=usa_map@data$iso_3166_2) -> centroids

# make it usable in ggplot2
usa_map <- fortify(usa_map)

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=usa_map, map=usa_map,
                    aes(long, lat, map_id=id),
                    color="#2b2b2b", size=0.1, fill=NA)
gg <- gg + geom_text(data=centroids, aes(x, y, label=state), size=2)
gg <- gg + coord_proj(us_laea_proj)
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg
```

[image]

Comment: this works great. Is there a way to move HI to the left of AK?

Comment: Never mind, I just use translation.